# C++ operator () overloading

Tags: c++

Could anybody explain what this code does?

```
struct EnumClass
    {
        template <typename T>
        std::size_t operator()(T t) const
        {
            return static_cast<std::size_t>(t);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are C++ functors and their uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It defines the operator `()` for any object of type `EnumClass`, taking one argument of any type. The operator evaluates to that argument, cast to type `size_t`.

```
EnumClass e;
e(1); // evaluates to (size_t)1
```

This is borderline nonsense, of course. (It might *make* sense in some other context, but stand-alone and as-is, it doesn't -- you don't need an `EnumClass` object to cast something to `size_t`.)